Understanding coercion of Box<Trait> to Box<dyn Trait>
I am just starting to learn Rust and if there is one topic that confused me it's coercion when it comes to trait objects.
trait Trait {
    fn test(&self) -> ();
}

struct A{
    num: u32
}

impl Trait for A{
    fn test(&self) -> (){
        print!("the num is {}", self.num);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A{
        num : 9
    };
    let bx: Box<A> = Box::new(a);
    let dynBx : Box<dyn Trait> = bx;
    dynBx.test();
}

from My understanding, Box<A> and Box<dyn Trait> are completely different types after generic monomorphization. That is, two Boxs will be created by the compiler one where the T = A and one where T = dyn Trait. There is no relationship between the two. Yet, the compiler has no issue coercing one into the other. How?
Say i wanted to define my own MyBox type, how can i get the same behavior of coercing MyBox<A> to MyBox<dyn Trait>?
